# Return from cURL tested with preg_match fails

Tags: php, preg-match

From cURL I´m getting back an response array where I´d like to test the body against a regex pattern. Here is a sample array:

```
Array ( [body] => 9068205463|admin [headers] => Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 16:45:56 GMT [2] => Server: Apache [3] => Vary: Accept-Encoding [4] => Content-Encoding: gzip [5] => Content-Length: 38 [6] => Connection: close [7] => Content-Type: text/html ) [engine] => cURL [cached] => )
```

Here is what my php if statement looks like:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}\|[a-zA-Z]+$/", $result['body'])) {
    die ("preg_match failed");
}
```

**Question: Why is Die() fired?**

Testing pattern here works like expected.
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b2W

Strange as this is working on my localhost but not on a production server.

Php Version is: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18 with Suhosin-Patch

Comment: Try to use: `trim($result['body'])` in `preg_match()`, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

Comment: perfect! it worked if you post this into an answer I will accept it ;)

Comment: trim worked @Being Sunny: what do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some spaces in your value and that's the reason why it doesn't matches the pattern.

To fix this simply use `trim()` in `preg_match()`, e.g.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}\|[a-zA-Z]+$/", trim($result['body']))) {
                                          //^^^^^     
    die ("preg_match failed");
}
```